# How to Replace Plastic Part of Threshold

Tags: doors

I had an exterior door threshold that shattered this week.

Is this part replaceable?  Or do I need a new door?

[image: Door threshold]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a new door, but you can't easily swap out a new complete threshold as the parts are integral to the frame.

You have a few possible avenues:

- Seek a replacement cap from the manufacturer. This is a somewhat proprietary part, so you're unlikely to find a generic part at hardware stores.
- Look for a replacement at your local lumber yard's boneyard. Judging by the foam pads at the bottom corners this is a decent brand, so maybe there are scratch-n-dent units to be found.
- Have a sheet metal shop bend you up a mill-finish or bronze aluminum cap in the same profile. (Bronze will show wear more readily as it gets scuffed.)
- Mill one yourself from vinyl stock or sealed hardwood. It likely just needs proper outer dimensions and a suitable channel on the underside.

Comment: I can get a close up if needed, but this is not a simple cap piece.  It has a wimpy I-shape underneath so that the plastic stands about half an inch above the wood.

Comment: That could be shimmed about a thousand different ways. Put on your bushcraft hat. :)

Comment: Indeed.  I was thining a decent piece of lumber might even be an upgrade.

Comment: It would, but it's in a vulnerable spot. If anything, use oak or ash and seal it well.